# List partition type GUID's for all disks from command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, disk, block-device

I need to list the [partition type GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)'s from the command line.

**Note: This is not the same as the partition UUID.**

Basically I'm needing to search for all disks that have the Ceph OSD type GUID:

```
4FBD7E29-9D25-41B8-AFD0-062C0CEFF05D
```

The intention is to emulate some things done with ceph-disk (python) in bash script on CoreOS.  Why? so I can mount them to the appropriate place automatically with ceph-docker.

Comment: Do you really need the GUID, not just the type that `fdisk -l` displays or the code that `gdisk -l` displays?

Comment: Good point.  I've also found that I might be able to grep on /dev/disk/by-parttypeuuid,

Comment: gdisk/fdisk displays them as "ceph data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my ultimate solution using `blkid -p`

```
function find_osds()
{
    local osds
    declare -a dev_list
    mapfile dev_list < <(lsblk -l -n -o NAME --exclude 1,7,11) # note -I not available in all versions of lsblk, use exclude instead
    for dev in "${dev_list[@]}"; do
        dev=/dev/$(trim "$dev")
        if blkid -p "$dev" | fgrep -q '4fbd7e29-9d25-41b8-afd0-062c0ceff05d'; then
            osds+=($dev)
        fi
    done
    echo "${osds[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`lsblk - list block devices` is your friend.

```
# lsblk -p -o NAME,PARTTYPE
NAME         PARTTYPE
/dev/vda     
├─/dev/vda1  c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
├─/dev/vda2  ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
...
```

Comment: Since the original question mentioned that this is for a script, the `-P` option to `lsblk` might be of interest which prints the desired values in a way that can be `eval`-ed in a shell script.

Comment: Root rights not required